# Speech to text fails using Google.cloud due to Attribute Error

Tags: python, installation, grpc

I am trying to run diarization of a conversation in a wav-file using `google.cloud`.

I have imported all the necessary libraries:

```py
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr  
import io
import argparse
import sys
import google.cloud
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'grpc' has no attribute 'StatusCode'
```

I have tried reinstalling packages:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall google-cloud-bigquery-storage
```

But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] to show the full traceback.